# SimpleExoplayerView plays audio, screen is white

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So I am trying to play a DASH video in a SimpleExoplayerView. I am following the most basic tutorials from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0.

The trouble is, I am able to hear the audio but the screen is always white.

Things I have already tried -

1. Using three different .mpd links. Can hear the audio each time and the video is white in each case. So there is no problem with the .mpd links.
2. Tested in different devices - an API 19 HTC Desire and an API 24 Moto G4. So I'm sure it is not a device specific issue.

Here is the initialising method -

```
private void initialisePlayer() {

    TrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory
            (defaultBandwidthMeter);

    if (exoPlayer == null) {

        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(context), new
                DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory), new DefaultLoadControl());

        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        DashMediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaResource();
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    }
}
```

And this is the buildMediaSource method -

```
 private DashMediaSource buildMediaResource() {

    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, getString(R.string.app_name));

    DataSource.Factory manifestDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);

    DashChunkSource.Factory dashChunkSourceFactory = new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(new
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, defaultBandwidthMeter));

    return new DashMediaSource.Factory(dashChunkSourceFactory, manifestDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri
            .parse(url));
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show link that you're trying to play?

Comment: These are two. I picked them up from the net for testing.

1. https://d2jyv85kc4p0re.cloudfront.net/ABtEOrCRSOSDDlcekhkSCA/manifest.mpd


2. https://media.axprod.net/TestVectors/v7-Clear/Manifest_1080p.mpd